# Connecting to a Server using VNC

Tags: vnc

I am following [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04) instructions to configure VNC on a server. At the end of Step 2, it says the following:

> New 'X' desktop is your_hostname:6

So now in Step 3 would I type the following:

```
ssh -L 5906:127.0.0.1:5906 -C -N -l sammy your_server_ip
```

instead of

`ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C -N -l sammy your_server_ip`

since the output is `New 'X' desktop is your_hostname:6` instead of `New 'X' desktop is your_hostname:1`

**Note:** I would replace `sammy` and  `your_server_ip` with my actual username and ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Since your example is "your_hostname:6" it should be on port 5906.

On the host where `vncserver` is running, you can verify that service is listening with:

```
sudo ss -tlnp
```

I'm assuming you may be getting an error message and that your connection is probably not actually working... But you'll need to update your post with the actual command and error message to troubleshoot it.