# Opening a web browser on VNC session

Tags: vnc

This is a follow up to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597496/connecting-to-a-server-using-vnc) question. I am able see the desktop, but I cannot see Chrome, Firefox etc. How do I open a web browser on a VNC session? Also, after sometime, I get the following error message:

```
$ ssh -L 5906:127.0.0.1:5906 -C -N -l sammy your_server_ip
sammmy@your_server_ip's password:
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer
```

Why am I getting this message?

Answer (score 1):

Probably could have edited your question to be more clear instead of posting a completely separate question.

> I am able see the desktop, but I cannot see Chrome, Firefox etc. How do I open a web browser on a VNC session?

If you can see the desktop via VNC, then you're probably just looking at a desktop environment that you're not familiar with... Try right clicking the desktop and see if "Xterm" or "Terminal" or something like that is an option.

Assuming Firefox is installed on that system (note - it's probably not)... You'll probably need to run `apt install firefox` or use `dnf` or some other packaging tool...

Once you have a remote terminal open, use `/usr/bin/firefox`

> Also, after sometime, I get the following error message:
> `client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer`

Your connection to that server isn't very good. One of the routers along the way is timing out your connection.

You can prove this to yourself by running `tightvnc` in a VM on your local machine, connect to it, and you should be able to go for hours without having the connection reset.

---

Note, usually it will be painfully slow to run a browser remotely. If you're trying to access some http service on the remote system, just forward the port directly for that service rather than using vnc.

Comment: How do I access a site on the remote system on my local machine?

Comment: You've already done it. You're using `ssh` to forward the ports for `tightvnc`...

Let's assume you want to connect to port 80 on your remote system, on your local system you could run: `ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:1080 -C -N -l sammy your_server_ip` (note that locally you want to use a port above `1024` otherwise you'll need root access)